# Map a Ruby array of timeseries values to a weighted interval

Tags: ruby, arrays, time

I have a Ruby array of arrays that represents a series of observations of a metric that's recorded over time. Each inner array has two elements:

- a `Time` instance in UTC describing when the observation was recorded
- the integer value of the observation

For example, we might have something like:

```
[
  [<Time: 2014-01-15 @ 18:00>, 100],
  [<Time: 2014-01-16 @ 06:00>, 200],
  [<Time: 2014-01-16 @ 12:00>, 300],
  [<Time: 2014-01-16 @ 23:00>, 400],
  [<Time: 2014-01-17 @ 12:00>, 500],
  [<Time: 2014-01-18 @ 03:00>, 600],
  [<Time: 2014-01-18 @ 06:00>, 700],
]
```

The problem at hand is to turn this into an array of the weighted values for each date:

```
[
  [<Date: 2014-01-15>, 100],
  [<Date: 2014-01-16>, 229],
  ...
]
```

The value for each day in the above array is obtained by the following procedure:

1. Break up the day into a series of intervals delimited by each observation and the boundaries of the day.

   > For example, since January 16th has observations at 06:00, 12:00, and 23:00, it is broken up into  intervals of 00:00-06:00, 06:00-12:00, 12:00-23:00, and 23:00-00:00.
2. The value of each interval is equal to the value of the observation at the beginning of the interval, or the last observation that was made if it's the start of the day.

   > For example, the value of the 06:00-12:00 interval on January 16th is **200**, since a value of 200 is recorded at 06:00.
   >
   > The value of the 00:00-06:00 interval on January 15th is **100**, since a value of 100 is the last observation that was recorded at the point the day started.
3. The weighted value of each interval is equal to its value multiplied by the fraction of the lengths of all the intervals in the day it occupied.

   > For example, the weighted value of the 06:00-12:00 interval on January 16th is **50** (200 * 0.25).
4. The final weighted value of each day is the sum of the weighted values of its intervals, coerced to an integer.

   > For example, the weighted value for January 16th is 229, because:
   >
   > `(100*(6/24) + 200*(6/24) + 300*(11/24) + 400*(1/24)).to_i = 229`

The first point in the array is a special case: the day starts there, rather than at 00:00, so January 15th has only one interval: 18:00-00:00 with a value of 100, so the weighted value is also 100.

Any suggestions on how to get started tackling this?

Comment: why the weighted value for January 16th is 229, because: `(100*(6/24) + 200*(6/24) + 300*(11/24) + 400*(1/24)).to_i = 229` has `(100*(6/24)`, since 100  is  from January 15th?

Comment: @Surya: The last point that was recorded when the day starts is from January 15th @ 18:00, so the value of 00:00-06:00 on January 16th is 100. I clarified point (2). Thanks!

Comment: John, you posted an interesting question. Your statement of the question is very well organized and presented.  So why no answers?  Beats me. I'll have one for you in awhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've assumed there are no days with no entries.

I found it convenient to first transform your array of `Time` objects. The rules I used for the transformation are as follows (`arb` refers to an arbitrary value, which may as well equal `val`):

- for the first day, replace the single element `[dt, val]` with the three elements:

  - `[dt1, val]`, where `dt1` is the same date at time `00:00:00`
  - `[dt2, arb]`, where `dt2` is the same date at time `23:59:59`
  - `[dt3, val]`, where `dt3` is one day later at time `00:00:00`
- for the last day, if `[dt, val]` is the last element for the day, add an element `[dt1, arb]`, where `dt` is the same date at time `23:59:59`.
- for every day other than the first and last, if `[dt, val]` is the last element for the day, add two elements:

  - `[dt1, arb]`, where `dt1` is the same date at time `23:59:59`
  - `[dt2, val]`, where `dt2` is one day later at time `00:00:00`

Suppose the following is your initial array. For clarity, I've used strings (allowing me to replace `"23:59:59"` with `"24:00"`):

```
arr = [
  ["2014-01-15 18:00", 100],

  ["2014-01-16 06:00", 200],
  ["2014-01-16 12:00", 300],
  ["2014-01-16 23:00", 400],

  ["2014-01-17 12:00", 500],

  ["2014-01-18 03:00", 600],
  ["2014-01-18 06:00", 700]
]
```

After applying the above rules, we obtain:

```
arr1 = [
  ["2014-01-15 00:00", 100],
  ["2014-01-15 24:00", 100],
  ["2014-01-16 00:00", 100],

  ["2014-01-16 06:00", 200],
  ["2014-01-16 12:00", 300],
  ["2014-01-16 23:00", 400],
  ["2014-01-16 24:00", 400],
  ["2014-01-17 00:00", 400],

  ["2014-01-17 12:00", 500],
  ["2014-01-17 24:00", 500],
  ["2014-01-18 00:00", 500],

  ["2014-01-18 03:00", 600],
  ["2014-01-18 06:00", 700],
  ["2014-01-18 24:00", 700]
]
```

or with elements grouped by date,

```
arr1 = [
  ["2014-01-15 00:00", 100],
  ["2014-01-15 24:00", 100],

  ["2014-01-16 00:00", 100],
  ["2014-01-16 06:00", 200],
  ["2014-01-16 12:00", 300],
  ["2014-01-16 23:00", 400],
  ["2014-01-16 24:00", 400],

  ["2014-01-17 00:00", 400],
  ["2014-01-17 12:00", 500],
  ["2014-01-17 24:00", 500],

  ["2014-01-18 00:00", 500],
  ["2014-01-18 03:00", 600],
  ["2014-01-18 06:00", 700],
  ["2014-01-18 24:00", 700]
]
```

Code to implement these rules should be straightforward. Once you have `arr1`, create an enumerator with [Enumerable#chunk](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):

```
enum = arr1.chunk { |a| a.first[0,10] } 
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x000001010e30d8>:each>
```

Let's see the elements of `enum`:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [["2014-01-15", [["2014-01-15 00:00", 100], ["2014-01-15 24:00", 100]]],
  #    ["2014-01-16", [["2014-01-16 00:00", 100], ["2014-01-16 06:00", 200],
  #      ["2014-01-16 12:00", 300], ["2014-01-16 23:00", 400],
  #      ["2014-01-16 24:00", 400]]],
  #    ["2014-01-17", [["2014-01-17 00:00", 400], ["2014-01-17 12:00", 500],
  #      ["2014-01-17 24:00", 500]]],
  #    ["2014-01-18", [["2014-01-18 00:00", 500], ["2014-01-18 03:00", 600],
  #      ["2014-01-18 06:00", 700], ["2014-01-18 24:00", 700]]]]
```

Now we need only map each element (one per date) into the weighted average of the `val`s (noting that we don't use the first element of each element of `enum`):

```
enum.map { |_,arr| (arr.each_cons(2)
                       .reduce(0.0) { |t,((d1,v1),(d2,_))|
                          t + min_diff(d2,d1)*v1 }/1440.0).round(2) }
  #=> [100.0, 229.17, 450.0, 662.5]
```

using the helper:

```
def min_diff(str1, str2)
  60*(str1[-5,2].to_i - str2[-5,2].to_i) + str1[-2,2].to_i - str2[-2,2].to_i 
end
```

Putting this together:

```
arr1.chunk { |a| a.first[0,10] }
    .map { |_,arr| (arr.each_cons(2)
                       .reduce(0.0) { |t,((d1,v1),(d2,_))| 
                          t + min_diff(d2,d1)*v1 }/1440.0).round(2) }
  #=> [100.0, 229.17, 450.0, 662.5]
```

along with the helper `min_diff`.

Comment: +1 for your helpfulness! I initially had something similar to this, but I was disturbed by all the magic numbers required (e.g. it would not be immediately obvious to another team member why "str1[-5,2]" is in the helper). I took an approach that grouped the array by day, then took the `k` elements in each day-array and made `k + 1` objects that are instances of a `Struct` called `Interval`. Then I made an `IntervalSet` object that took the `Interval`s and computes the right answer. :)

Comment: Also, there's a couple of bugs: Enumerable#chunk only works correctly if the array is already sorted (which isn't guaranteed by the problem description). So this also requires a presort step to be right, I think.

Comment: I did say "once you have `arr1`...", which I show as sorted, but yes, either the code that converts `arr` to `arr1` will have to produce a sorted `arr1` or you'll have to insert a `sort_by` between `arr1` and `chunk`.

Comment: Gotcha. It wasn't clear to me that you were assuming a sort step, but makes sense.